# Backslash representation on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, editor

So I came across a confusing scenario while answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916062/hardcoding-a-windows-path-and-escaping-the-backslashes/28916097#28916097) question.

To explain simply if I need to include  double slashes or escape sequence Backslash in C#   I need to include it as three slashes.

So here it is :

- \ - single slash : Fine
- \\  - Double slash : Not fine , simply go to edit this post and you see there are three slashes (`\\\`)

When answering we tend to include blockquotes as I have done in that particular question. And if we do not put a bit attention we might mislead the reading person by including a false information.

Ex :- C:\files.txt  **vs** C:\\files.txt.  (Go to edit of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916062/hardcoding-a-windows-path-and-escaping-the-backslashes/28916097#28916097), I used three slashes )

Is this a known feature/bug/weakness of Stack Exchange or simply it's us, answering person duty to verify for such things?

Also I think proper communication to new users would be great on such cases hence providing accurate answers is a must.

Comment: How would you implement escaping special-characters (like `*` in markdown), if you don't have any escape-character? So, not a bug.

Comment: So simply said we must put attention on such cases when posting answers ? :)

Comment: Yes, you must put attention.  That's kinda cool, actually; I didn't know you could escape backslashes that way.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - yes I too came across only after putting the quote from msdn. Now I wonder how many places I might have put the double slashes which becomes one slash making an answer bit invalid. Good if this could be noted or mentioned in a guide or somewhere.

Comment: There's always backticks.

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://i.imgur.com/Ug0xWcU.png (sfw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the normal functioning of Markdown:

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with literal asterisks (instead of an HTML  tag), you can use backslashes before the asterisks, like this:
>
> `\*literal asterisks\*`
>
> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> \   backslash

--[Markdown: Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)